# How to remove "find me" button from Google Maps widget in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have my own "Find Me" button (A on the picture), so I need no Google's (B on the picture).

[image]

How to remove it?

Simultaneously, I need my current location marker.

My initialization is following:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        moveCameraInternal(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        if( Util.isLocationPermissionGranted(this) ) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(onCameraMoveListener);

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);`

Should do the trick.